# Ruby: Sorting except one element

Tags: ruby, sorting, alphabetical

I am trying to sort string elements in array. Let's say I want to sort it [b, e, f, t, g], but want to keep e in first in ruby. So the result should be [e, b, f, g, t]. How can I write a code in ruby that sort the array that way.

Comment: What if there is more than one `e`?

Comment: let's sat there is just one e; it's just example; I would use 'default' in my case

Comment: `arr.sort.unshift(arr.delete('e'))`. Only works for an array of unique characters and the `'e'` must exist else you'll get a `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

```
["b", "e", "f", "t", "g"] .sort_by { |s| [s == 'e' ? 0 : 1, s] }
  #=> ["e", "b", "f", "g", "t"]
```

Here [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) uses [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to compare each pair of elements computed by the block, such as `[0, "e"]` and `[1, "b"]`. See the third paragraph of the doc for `Array#<=>`.

Comment: You could also use `s == 'e' ? '' : “ #{s}“` or better yet `"#{ s unless s == 'e'}"` assuming no `nil` elements or empty strings

Answer (score 2):

You could partition the `Array` into all the "e"'s and all the not "e"'s then reduce them back together like so

```
  arr = ["b", "e", "f", "t", "e","g"]
  arr.partition {|e| e == 'e'}.reduce {|e,not_e| e.concat(not_e.sort)}
  #=> ["e", "e", "b", "f", "g", "t"]
```

Additional credit to [@iGian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5239030/igian) for

```
  arr.sort.partition {|e| e == 'e'}.flatten
  #=> ["e", "e", "b", "f", "g", "t"]
```

Comment: Good idea with `partition`! Also `arr.sort.partition {|e| e == 'e'}.flatten`

Comment: @iGian worth adding for sure

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one option more, converting to an Hash:

```
ary = [:b, :e, :f, :t, :g, :e]
ary.sort.group_by(&:itself).then { |h| h.delete(:e) + h.values.flatten }
```

It returns the array keeping all `:e` in front. `:e` must exist.

```
#=> [:e, :e, :b, :f, :g, :t]
```

The first part is returning the sorted grouping hash:

```
ary.sort.group_by(&:itself) #=> {:b=>[:b], :e=>[:e, :e], :f=>[:f], :g=>[:g], :t=>[:t]}
```

---

For the method to work even **when `:e` is not present**:

```
ary.sort.group_by(&:itself).then { |h| h.delete(:e).to_a + h.values.flatten }
```

Since `nil.to_a #=> []`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 arr.sort.reject{|x| x=="e"}.unshift('e')
```

If you have more than "e" in the array then it will ignore all 'e'.